# Android: How to make clickable arrows for a point and click game?

Tags: android, button, click

[image: What I got at the moment]
I'd like to have an arrow at the end of the road and another one to go back like this:

[image: Like this]

I have just started with Android Studio.

I tried doing

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/Street1720x1280"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:
        android:pointerIcon="arrow">
    </Button>
   </LinearLayout>`
```

But it doesn't show any arrows and I don't know how I can change its position.